# HTACCESS RewriteCond and RewriteRule grouping

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a htaccess file which redirects all files to the root `index.php` file unless certain conditions are met.

The following code works perfectly and is used to provide placeholder images for uploaded media assets if the website is run locally. This is to not need to download all files from the website so that the repository only consists of files.

The files that the following rules match look like:

```
[\d]{1,}.(thumbnail|medium|large).[\w]+
```

What I want to do is match the middle group and use it in the redirect rule but cannot seem to get it to work with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} data/applications/.*/media/image/.*/[\d]+\.(.*)\.[\w]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .*$ data/applications/app/www/img/temp.$1.jpg [L]
```

The original code is here:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} data/applications/.*/media/image/.*/[\d]+\.thumbnail\.[\w]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .*$ data/applications/app/www/img/temp.thumbnail.jpg [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} data/applications/.*/media/image/.*/[\d]+\.medium\.[\w]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .*$ data/applications/app/www/img/temp.medium.jpg [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} data/applications/.*/media/image/.*/[\d]+\.large\.[\w]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .*$ data/applications/app/www/img/temp.large.jpg [L]
```

How can i combine the 3 separate matches into one rule?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a single rules as this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(data/applications)/.*/media/image/.*/\d+\.([^.]+)\.\w+$ $1/app/www/img/temp.$2.jpg [L]
```